# How to infer local precipitation from reanalysis data?

Tags: precipitation, reanalysis, weatherdata

Let's say I'm extracting precipitation from a single pixel or region from a reanalysis (MERRA-2, ERA-5, Interim) dataset.

I can infer a distribution for the daily data (Gamma, Pearson-III, e.g. [link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2118/8e1e04ab60c68dabc6c20e254953c4501c98.pdf)), but I know that it will be **conservative** since I'm basing the distribution on a reanalysis product (smoothed, spatially averaged out).

Is there an **appropriate method to approximate the "real/actual" local precipitation distribution** from a reanalysis dataset?

Comment: you can only divide the pixel value by the grid box size and get an approximate value.

Comment: I meant grid box area not grid box size. Reanalysis is not the correct way to get local precipitation distribution. For that you need rain gauges.

Comment: Be aware that even rain gauges can have large errors, in particular automated ones.  A leaf gets stuck and suddenly it "stops raining".  It happens.